# How to write a simple custom js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a custom js plugin which needs to get initiated if there is a data attribute included in my HTML:

```
<input value="98" data-my-plugin="number">
```

If data-my-plugin is included, I want to initiate my js or jquery plugin automatically.

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Answer (score 2):

You can  use `.ready()`, attribute selector `"[data-my-plugin]"` or `"[data-my-plugin=number]"`

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    "myPlugin": function() {
      // do stuff
      return this.val()
    }
  });
}(jQuery));

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("[data-my-plugin]").myPlugin());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input value="98" data-my-plugin="number">
```